# perl fork and killing child after timeout

Tags: perl, fork

```
my $pid = fork();
if ($pid)
{
   sleep 5;
   waitpid($pid,0);
}
if ($pid == 0) 
{
   sub1();
   exit 0;
} 
else
{
   exit;
}
```

I just need to clarify whether this code is bug free or not !

I need to keep the parent alive and create asynchronous child processes 24x7 and once a child finished execution it should be terminated, without waiting for parent process to terminate.

Comment: It doesn't even try kill anything, for starters...

Comment: Your code does spawns a child and parent do waits for the child process to terminate.

Comment: Sorry, exit 0 must terminate the child. Thats what i meant killing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will do the following:

1. Fork a child.
2. Parent sleeps 5 seconds and then blocks waiting in `waitpid` for child to exit.
3. Meanwhile, child runs `sub1()` and then terminates with `exit 0`. The child doesn't care about or wait for the parent.
4. When the child has exited, the parent continues into the `else` section and terminates: `exit`